# Image and Sound metadata/data libraries in Java

Tags: java, groovy

Can someone let me know if there are java libraries that can help me doing the below

1. get image width, height, color space (RGB/CMYK), dpi
2. get information on WAV audio data: bitrate, sampling rate, channels, length & verify it's PCM Audio

Comment: Have you tried [JMF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioFileFormat%28java.io.File%29) will return all the data you need about a WAV file, or any other supported by the standart java library.

[`ImageIO.read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) will load the file into a [`BufferedImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) and you can get all the properties from it. You might have some problems with getting the dpi.

Answer (score 1):

JavaLayer project i recommended to one uni. undegraduate students for the uni project few years back. It may worth to look into : http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/documents.html